# Regex of shortcode in Php

Tags: php, regex

I don't know what the title of the question should be. This something logical and what I lack is the same.

I have a string in the format `[CONST att1="value1" att2="value2"]` and created a regex that was working fine. But certain conditions made this regex wrong.

```
$data = preg_split('/(?<=\")\s/', $replace_str[1]);
foreach ($data as $index_val => $exp_data) {
    if(!empty($exp_data)){
        $attributes = explode('=',$exp_data);
        if(count($attributes) > 0){
            $index = strtolower(str_replace(array("'", "\""), "", trim($attributes[0])));
            $item_value = str_replace(array("'", "\""), "", trim($attributes[1]));
            $item_value = $attributes[1];
            $array_data[$index] = $item_value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then using the array to get key value. But in some instance, say if the format is like the one below

`[CONST att1="value1" att2= "value2"]`

the exploded variable contains  `"value2"` (notice the prefixed space). What i want is `"value2"`.

So since my format is similar to that of WordPress shortcode referred *shortcode.php* file in WordPress and found `@[<>&/\[\]\x00-\x20=]@` inside the file. But I am unable to understand or make it work.

I need to access `value1` and `value2` as clean data. i.e, without spaces, single and double quotes at the start and end. Also if the order of the `att1` and `att2` is changed, it should work.

`[CONST att2="value2" att1="value1"]`

Should output:

> array(att1=>value1,att2=>value2)

Comment: What is the final output you want to get? `Array
(
    [[const att1] => "value1"
    [att2] => "value2"]
)` ? Why not collect all the data with a single matching regex? Do all attributes have values?

Comment: I want to use that value1 and value2 for some purpose. My requirement is that value1 and value2 should not contain any starting and ending spaces, single quotes and double qoutes. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Desired output is not correct as in my question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think you meant https://3v4l.org/RluqR

Comment: Sorry, https://3v4l.org/RY4U3. @Nick I thought of using `array_combine`, but I used it before shifting and it did not work... Well, that is just a possible solution, too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's worth posting as an answer.

Comment: You're trying to write a parser (albeit a limited one). Be aware that these are notoriously difficult to write with regex. It depends how much variation there will be in your input strings. For example, what happens if the `value` contains quote marks, or spaces, or equal signs, or other escaped characters. If your parser needs to deal with these things, then your regex will be very complex and probably quite brittle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest collecting keys and values in the shortcode string using a matching regex with `preg_match_all` like

```
'~(?:\G(?!\A)\s+|^\[\w+\s+)\K([^\s=]*)\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ehx0qN/2/).

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)\s+|^\[\w+\s+)`
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `([^\s=]*)` - Group 1 (attribute name): 0+ chars other than whitespace and `=`
- `\s*=\s*` - a `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `"` - a double quotation mark
- `([^"]*)` -  Group 2 (attribute value inside quotes): any 0+ chars other than `"`
- `"` - a double quotation mark

After you get an array of matches you will have to build your associative array "manually" like

```
$s = '[CONST att1="value1" att2="value2"]';
preg_match_all('/(?:\G(?!\A)\s+|^\[\w+\s+)\K(\w+)\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"/', $s, $array_data, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
$res = [];
foreach ($array_data as $kvp) {
    $res[$kvp[1]] =  $kvp[2];
}
print_r($res);
// -> Array ( [att1] => value1 [att2] => value2 )
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/RY4U3).

Another way of processing the matches ([demo](https://3v4l.org/S7UOa)):

```
if (preg_match_all('/(?:\G(?!\A)\s+|^\[\w+\s+)\K(\w+)\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"/', $s, $array_data)) {
    array_shift($array_data);
    print_r(array_combine($array_data[0], $array_data[1]));
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find anything complex in wordpress shortcodes. So i thougth i can do the same way

Comment: @Shadow If it works, please consider accepting. If you need clarifications, please let me know

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. Just need to know if there is not more than 15 strings in this format, using preg_replace_callback affects performance or is it the best one ?

Comment: @Shadow If you can do what you need with `preg_replace`, you should prefer `preg_replace`. If you need to further manipulate the matches use `preg_replace_callback`.